# Gallery view for products

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, gallery

I want to create a gallery view, for want of a better word as I dont really know exactly what it is called or what to look for.

Ideally bootstrap compliant or mobile friendly. I want to display products as images in strips, here is exactly the sort of thing I want to replicate but I dont know what API or even what to look for really.

[Gallery menu](http://stopka.cz/en/sortiment)

Can anybody tell me what this would be called or if they know a tutorial or plugin that can achieve this?

Sorry if this question isnt specific enough.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Horizontal Accordion**

you can get help from other widget websites

[see dynamic drive](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/haccordion.htm)

Comment: Thanks I will give that a go, have you used it?